# Does it Make Sense to Dynamically Add EC2 Instance Private IPs to Django's CACHE LOCACTION Setting in an Elastic Beanstalk Environment with NGINX?

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, memcached

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk with load balancing and I've set a minimum number of instances to 2. So I have two instances with two different private IPs.

What I'm trying to achieve is to add Memcached caching locations dynamically to Django's `CACHES` setting based on the EC2 instances that exist in an environment.

**My Primary Question**

Since Elastic Beanstalk uses NGINX (in my case), do I need to dynamically add the instance IPs to Django's CACHES location? Or would setting `'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',` be sufficient for all running EC2 instances?

**Secondary Question**
Does NGINX centralize the cache for all running instances?

My NGINX primary config:

```
(staging) [ec2-user@ip-172-31-9-242 conf.d]$ cat elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf 
location / {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

The Django documentation says the same cache can be shared across multiple servers - [Memcached caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/topics/cache/):

> One excellent feature of Memcached is its ability to share a cache
> over multiple servers. This means you can run Memcached daemons on
> multiple machines, and the program will treat the group of machines as
> a single cache, without the need to duplicate cache values on each
> machine. To take advantage of this feature, include all server
> addresses in LOCATION, either as a semicolon or comma delimited
> string, or as a list.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyMemcacheCache',
        'LOCATION': [
            '172.19.26.240:11211',
            '172.19.26.242:11211',
        ]
    }
}
```

I made a class using boto3 to get a list of EC2 instances:

```
class MemcachedLocations(object):

    MEMCACHED_PORT = "11211"
    ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_S3_SECRET_KEY_ID')
    REGION = 'us-west-2'

    @cached_property
    def get(self):

        client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=self.REGION, aws_access_key_id=self.ACCESS_KEY,
                              aws_secret_access_key=self.SECRET_KEY)

        response = client.describe_instances()

        private_ips_list = []
        for reservation in response['Reservations']:
            for instance in reservation['Instances']:
                private_ip = instance['PrivateIpAddress']
                private_ip = f"{private_ip}:{self.MEMCACHED_PORT}"
                private_ips_list.append(private_ip)

        return private_ips_list
```

It works as expected when deployed:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.CACHES
{'default': 
    {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyMemcacheCache',
     'LOCATION': ['172.##.##.###:11211', '172.##.##.###:11211']
    }
}
```

but when I test it in SSH:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set('ping', 'pong', 600)
cache.get('ping')
>>> Returns None but should return 'pong' if working properly
```

Sidenote: I already know about AWS Elasticache. I already know how to implement it successfully. I'd like to not use it, if possible.